# Swift 3.0 AVAudioPlayer Playing audio over music

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avaudioplayer

Currently this is the code I'm using to play my sound during the button press.

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sound/yatch", withExtension: "mp3")!

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Im trying to get this audio to run over whats currently playing (etc Spotify, pandora, Music). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the audio session of your application to play over the currently playing audio:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```

According to the `AVAudioSession` headers, `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` will play audio with music, etc.

```
/*  Use this category for background sounds such as rain, car engine noise, etc.
 Mixes with other music. */
public let AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient: String
```

Comment: Also is there any way to play the sound without switching the ringer to sound? Just keeping it on the vibrate position. I was looking through the reference AVFoundation from Apple and couldn't find anything

Comment: I want to play sound from URL http://site4brandz.com/cphp/26/uploads/KaabilHoon.mp3 But its giving Error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)

Comment: @MaheshNarla You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.3 Update

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "INSERT_FILENAME", withExtension: "wav") else { return }

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)
    audioPlayer.volume = 1

    audioPlayer.play()

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```