# How can I play a sound in swift without stopping the playing music?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

I'm using AVAudio to play a sound, but when I do so, the music (In the music app) stops.

```
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    func playSound(sound: String, type: String) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: type) {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                audioPlayer?.play()
            } catch {
                print("ERROR")
            }
        }
    }
    // Some code here
    playSound(sound: "resume", type: "m4a")
```

I want to make the sound act like a notification soud and that the music keeps playing. Any way to do this?

Comment: [Swift 3.0 AVAudioPlayer Playing audio over music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312216/swift-3-0-avaudioplayer-playing-audio-over-music) might help too, else use the updated function in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set your `AVAudioSession` to [`.duckOthers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616618-duckothers) or [`.mixWithOthers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616611-mixwithothers):

(Before you play sounds):

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        .setCategory(.playback, options: .duckOthers)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        .setActive(true)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You will first have to define properties of an `AVAudioSession`. This lets you chose how to play the sound with the help of [`setCategory(_:mode:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1771734-setcategory). What you need is this:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
func playSound(sound: String, type: String) {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: type) {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print("ERROR")
        }
    }
}
// Some code here
playSound(sound: "resume", type: "m4a")
```

Feel free to experiment with the `setCategory` function by passing different configuration options. You can also read more about [`mixWithOthers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616611-mixwithothers), but the key point is:

> An option that indicates whether audio from this session mixes with audio from active sessions in other audio apps.